# Make TikZ compute the x-coordinate of the margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

The command `\hrulefill` prints a line that fills all empty horizontal space with a line. I would like to do something similar with `TikZ`.

What I would like to know is can I do something similar like

```
\noindent Some text \hrulefill
```

with `TikZ`?

What I would like to do is for `TikZ` to be able to determine the x-coordinate of the margin so that I can do something like

```
\tikz Some text \draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (end of textwidth,0);
```

For more information, you can see my answer in [Best way to insert a horizontal cut line with a scissor symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70792/best-way-to-insert-a-horizontal-cut-line-with-a-scissor-symbol/70802#70802).

Comment: I am not sure about what you are asking but if assume things right, you perhaps want `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\textwidth`. I'll add a picture in another comment.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16419/86

Comment: Image: http://imgur.com/9Ftq0 
Code: `Some text \tikz \draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (0.8\textwidth, 0);` You could tweak the `0.8` to any number <1, perhaps, that would be obvious.

Comment: @KannappanSampath, that is what I tried to do in the link I gave in my question. I would like `TikZ` (or TeX) to be able to automatically set the coordinates of the margin so that I would no longer need to set the coordinates by hand every time I change my margin size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution based on package `zref-savepos`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{zref-savepos,zref-user}
\providecommand*{\zsaveposx}{\zsavepos}% for older versions
\newcounter{dashlinecnt}
\renewcommand*{\thedashlinecnt}{%
  dashline-\the\value{dashlinecnt}%
}
\newcommand*{\dashedlinefill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \stepcounter{dashlinecnt}%
  \zsaveposx{\thedashlinecnt-a}%
  \zrefused{\thedashlinecnt-a}% 
  % \zrefused{\thedashlinecnt-b}% can be omitted
  \rlap{%
    \tikz\draw[dashed](0,0) -- %
    (\zposx{\thedashlinecnt-b}sp-\zposx{\thedashlinecnt-a}sp,0);%
  }%
  \hfill
  \zsaveposx{\thedashlinecnt-b}%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A\hfill B

\noindent
Hello World \dashedlinefill

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result using zref-savepos]

### Solution based on `tikz`' `remember picture`

(Update: `overlay` added for first `\tikz` command.)

This is explained in section **16.13 Referencing Nodes Outside the Current Pictures**.
The example also needs option `overlay` for the first `\tikz` command to avoid a shift of the first node and a line with a slight slope.

(Second update:) The reason is that `\tikz` uses a drawing area with a minimal width and height of `1pt`. Thus instead of `overlay` also

```
minimum width=0pt,
minimum height=0pt,
```

can be used for the first `\tikz`. The second `\tikz` still requires `overlay` of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{dashlinecnt}
\renewcommand*{\thedashlinecnt}{%
  dashline-\the\value{dashlinecnt}%
}
\newcommand*{\dashedlinefill}{%
  \leavevmode
  \stepcounter{dashlinecnt}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt]\node(\thedashlinecnt){};%
  \hfill
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt]\draw[dashed](\thedashlinecnt) -- (0,0);%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
A\hfill B

\noindent
Hello World \dashedlinefill

\end{document}
```

This solution also needs two LaTeX runs. However, in this case a rerun warning is not provided by `tikz`.

> [image: Result based on tikz]

Comment: When I have time I'll go over that part of the pgf manual.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to fill only the current line, then you can use the macro after `\tikz ...;`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\hdashfill{%
  \leavevmode%
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ 7pt{\hss\rule[1ex]{4pt}{0.5pt}\rule{3pt}{0pt}}\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Some text \hdashfill

\tikz\node at(0,0){Some text};\hdashfill

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an humble attempt:

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\sometext}
\settowidth{\sometext}{Some Text }
\noindent Some Text \tikz \draw[dashed](0,0)--({\linewidth-\sometext},0);

%Another variant that Percusse suggested on chat, thanks to Percusse
%This works better in terms of output than the above. I guess the space after 
%text in "Some text  " is not being counted. 

\noindent Some Text \tikz{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylen}{width("Some Text ")}
\draw[dashed](0,0)-- ({\the\linewidth-\mylen},0);}

\noindent\tikz \draw[dashed](0,0)--({\textwidth-0.4},0);

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: :-)]

## Acknowledgements

Thanks to Andrew Stacey who helped with a lot of this code and Percusse who suggested some polishing, which leaves open the question of what my contribution is.