# Insert line between minipage but not at page end

Tags: minipage

I am doing a PHP script to write a `.tex` file.

Based in this [insert a horizontal cut line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70792/best-way-to-insert-a-horizontal-cut-line-with-a-scissor-symbol), I want to "print" many block on one page, and between block I want draw a "cut line".

**But I dont want draw a cut line at bottom of page.**

The script write:

- BLOCK
- LINE
- BLOCK
- LINE
- BLOCK
- ...

For this example I am using `minipage` to avoid break the "block" and inserting the cut line between this "blocks"

**EDITED** *now with an cycle method*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, tmargin=8mm, bmargin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
This line its for fix width \\
% JUST REPEAT BLOCK MANY TIMES (NOT REAL BUT WORKS FOR EXAMPLE)
\foreach \n in {1,...,3}{
    % START BLOCK
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \textbf{{\large Block Number \n}} \\
        \lipsum[2-4]
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \noindent\dotfill\ding{33}\dotfill
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    % END BLOCK
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Code]

As you can see in the image, the cut line it pointless at the end of the page, it does not should to be drawn/inserted

I think it can be solved using something like `needspace`, but I would not know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a while reading the package `needspace` I try to write a command `cutline` based in `needspace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor} % For cycle
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\cutline}[1]{\par \penalty-100\begingroup
        \setlength{\dimen@}{#1+6\baselineskip} % Sum space of block and cutline
        \dimen@ii\pagegoal \advance\dimen@ii-\pagetotal
        \ifdim \dimen@>\dimen@ii
            \ifdim \dimen@ii>\z@
                \vfil
            \fi
            \break
        \else
            \vspace{\baselineskip}
            \noindent\dotfill\ding{33}\dotfill
            \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \fi
        \endgroup}
\makeatother

\def\one{1}
\newlength{\blockheight}

\begin{document}

% JUST REPEAT BLOCK MANY TIMES (NOT REAL BUT WORKS FOR EXAMPLE)
\foreach \n in {1,...,20}{
    \def\newblock{ % SET BLOCK DATA
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \textbf{{\large Block Number \n}} \\
            \lipsum[4-1]
        \end{minipage}      
    }
    \settoheight\blockheight{\newblock} % GET HEIGHT OF NEXT BLOCK
    \ifnum \n>1 % SKIP FIRST BLOCK
        \cutline{\blockheight} % PRINT CUTLINE OR BREAK BASED ON NEXT BLOCK HEIGHT
    \fi
    \newblock % PRINT BLOCK
}
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: Result]

I want to clarify two things:

- Obviously in the generation of the .tex will be detected if the block is the first, so as not to insert a cutline.
- If there is a better proposal, I will accept it.